# Access object using string value using ThymeLeaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have two class objects. EX: 
object1 = "varName";
varName = "value";

I want to get the value which varName contains. I have used the following expression, but thymeleaf is giving error.

${${object1}}.

> ${object1} should replaced with varName - ${varName} , so, I can get the value as "value".

Please help me to solve this issue. object1 values will be runtime value, that can be changed based on runtime values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this scenario. I have used Preprocessing in Thymeleaf.

> ${_${object1}__}.

It works for me.